# modules when goes through infine...?

Tags: c#-4.0

```
lim pn=0
n→∞
p=every inch that estimate be correct
n=number of modules
```

if we have a big application with alot modules ... according formule above, we face with problems for black test or white..it means it go toward 0 (estimate be correct every application with n modules) and its bad.its good with less modules and it close p toward 1 but when n grows toward big number sth like ∞ our p get close to 0
so what development do in big applications ?still oop (different modules and classes?) i hope someone understand my question!

Comment: I hope someone understands it too. Please explain what you mean by "modules"? Do you mean classes, projects or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the ability to prove that an application is correct, and that this becomes harder as the number of modules increases?

One idea behind OOP is to break a complex system into smaller sub-systems (classes, modules, whatever you want to call them) that are easier to prove correct in isolation.  The theory is that by then combining the correct modules, we can build a correct system.

Obviously it's more complicated than that, but that's my understanding of the basic philosophy.